# Nameserver not resolving for all locations

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, domain-registrar

I have a problem with a domain name not resolving the nameservers correctly. I am not sure where else I can ask for help. I have spent a total of about 5 hours on support line chat or on the phone with two different registrars and I still am no closer to solving the issue.

The problem can be summed up with this picture:
[Nameserver not resolving tuccopizza.es on dnschecker.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF0zY.png)
So the nameservers are working for some locations globally, but not in Ireland, where I am based. I initially had the domain with namecheap with nameservers from cloudflare. They told me the problem was with cloudflare and I should contact them. I was certain that this was not the case and so I switched to using namecheaps NS and set the A and CNAME to point to the website. After experiencing the same issue, I contacted namecheap again who told me that the problem was with the server hosting the website, and I should contact them. I knew this was not the issue and thought that it may be down to the registrar, so I switched registrar to Godaddy.

On Godaddy the same issue occured. They also blamed cloudflare when I called them so I switched to Godaddys NS and left their default parking page. This way they could not blame the hosting server. Now, several more phone calls later, in which they all told me to wait 24 hrs after being on the phone for close to an hour every time, I am no closer to having the issue fixed. I am going to call them in a few hours again, but I expect I will be told to wait another 24hrs.

**Has anyone experienced something similar and if so how were you able to fix this?**

I have a feeling this is also happening with another domain too (tosty.com.es), though that is still on the cloudflare NS so they will just blame cloudflare if I mention it. I will probably switch to Godaddys NS with this domain and try the same phone calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As witnessed in https://dnsviz.net/d/tuccopizza.es/dnssec/  you have a DNSSEC related problem. In short your domain is not configured correctly, and since DNSSEC is not 100% fully deployed everywhere it means some people will see errors and not others.

In short, the registry publishes a DS record for your name, hinting that it is DNSSEC configured, however your nameservers do not publish the corresponding DNSKEY record, which is an immediat DNSSEC misconfiguration error.

Your solution, if you do not want to set up DNSSEC properly, is to go at the registrar managing your domain name and through it remove the DS records at the registry. Waiting a few hours/days after that, your name should resolve everywhere correctly.

DNSviz output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I am really grateful for your answer.
After looking into what you wrote I read about DNSSEC and the current DNSSEC settings on the Registrar, Godaddy. Please point out if this is incorrect:

Godaddy do not support DNSSEC for .es domains (https://ie.godaddy.com/help/manage-dnssec-for-my-domain-6115). However, I also had an option to purchase it. My conclusion is that they either do not support it or they do not support it for free. This means DNSSEC is not an option for me.

Comment: Further, it must mean that DNSSEC was enabled prior to the transfer to my account, and these settings were already applied to the domain and they were kept in the transfer. As DNSSEC was not enabled on my account, it caused the issues I was seeing.

The fix would be as you mentioned, to disable DNSSEC for this domain. I do not have the option to do this, so I will have to contact Godaddy support and ask them to disable it.

Many, many thanks for helping me on this issue!!

Comment: Transferring a domain name between registrars when it is DNSSEC enabled is indeed always a big problem (more precisely it is changing the DNS provider that is a problem) and the safest route is to remove DNSSEC before transferring the domain. Now if the documentation you found is correct it means indeed you will need to contact support for them to change things manually. It may take time.

Comment: Also morale of the story: for any DNS related problems, I heavily suggest a first stop at DNSviz to do a checkup, it will pick up many different problems, not only those related to DNSSEC. Any problem seen by DNSviz should be addressed. There exists other tools online to do checks, but I prefer DNSviz far over the others, in part due to its graphical display. You also have another tool called Zonemaster  but it is purely textual .

Comment: In the end phone calls were not enough. They created a ticket with an incident number and I replied to the ticket by email and sent the link: https://dnsviz.net/d/tuccopizza.es/dnssec/   I asked them to remove the DNSSEC and eventually they did. Problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That’s not a Cloudflare error. Something on your server is blocking access. 
Check your server logs. 
It’s also possible your host is doing some sort of blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you another way to escape from this problem.

You can use CDN'S [Content Delivery Network]

> CDN -- Content delivery network has data centers in different
>   geographical locations.
>
> Also when your site is using a CDN and a reader opens your site, your
>   files (images, staticfiles, etc.) are served from the nearest data
>   center of the CDN you are using.
>
> [Refer the CDN for cloudflare](https://www.a2hosting.com/blog/enable-cloudflare/)

This is my suggestion, Try at your interest.